# Can I view ArcScene 3D models in a free viewer such as ArcReader or another 3rd party viewer?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, 3d, export, arcscene, 3d-analyst

I would like to build a complex 3D model in ArcScene, export it and send it to someone else that does not have ArcGIS with 3D Analyst. The idea is to interactively navigate the model during a presentation.

I've never used ArcReader or ArcGIS publisher before so I have no idea if a complex 3D model can be published and exported.

If not what are my alternatives for viewing the completed model outside if ArcGIS?

Answer (score 1):

If the model is a multipatch, you could try converting it to [Collada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA) using [Multipatch To Collada (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Multipatch_To_Collada/001200000049000000/). You could then view it in a number of different free software such as Google Earth.

Comment: Thanks, that's not going to work because there [appears to a bug with the Multipatch to Collada export](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13515/how-can-i-sucessfully-import-3d-surface-and-features-from-arcgis-10-into-sketchu) when exporting complex features and surfaces.

Comment: Now I remember that question... did you contact ESRI support about it? Any luck with FME/Data Interop?

Comment: Did not report this one. I've contacted ESRI before and got a few bugs confirmed but it takes time commitment to report and discuss and its usually a long time before they resolve and implement fixes if ever.  Unfortunately, time is not what I have so I try to find workarounds to move on.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the data into ArcGlobe and from there export to ArcReader format, open in ArcReader and you have your 3D display.